# clj-time and displaying in user's time zone

Tags: datetime, clojure, timezone, clj-time

I've been playing around with to-local-date-time, org.joda.time.DateTimeZone/getDefault, formatters, etc. and I still can't figure out how to get a datetime which I've stored as UTC to display in the user's time zone. Some formatters I can get to display the time, but it shows UTC time with an offset. If I have 2013-10-05T19:02:25.641-04:00, for example, how can I get it to display "2013-10-05 14:02:25"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can can apply the timezone with `clj-time.core/to-time-zone`, using `clj-time.core/time-zone-for-offset` when you only have the target offset, to get the localized time from your stored UTC.

There are numerous existing UTC formatters in the `clj-time.format/formatters` map, but you can always create your own from `clj-time.format/formatter`, or `clj-time.format/formatter-local`, and `clj-time.format/unparse`.

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t]
         '[clj-time.format :as f])

(defn formatlocal [n offset]
  (let [nlocal (t/to-time-zone n (t/time-zone-for-offset offset))]
    (f/unparse (f/formatter-local "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa")
               nlocal)))

(formatlocal (t/now) -7)
```

Comment: If you use `hh` in the pattern, you should also use `aa`. Otherwise, use `HH`.

Comment: True. Updated my sample to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's better to use build in timezone support from the formatter

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t]
         '[clj-time.format :as f])
(def custom-time-formatter (f/with-zone (f/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                                        (t/default-time-zone)))
(f/unparse custom-time-formatter (t/now))
```

instead of `(t/default-time-zone)` you can use a specific timezone or an offset (see clj-time.core documentation)

(maybe that didn't work in 2013 :) )

Answer (score 3):

`2013-10-05T19:02:25.641-04:00` **is** the local time which would be UTC time `2013-10-05T23:02:25.641Z`.

If you have a valid UTC time, do **not** try to convert it with `to-local-date-time`! `to-local-date-time` is a convenience function for changing the time zone on a DateTime instance without converting the time. To properly convert the time, use `to-time-zone` instead.

To format a DateTime without time zone information, use a custom formatter. Your example would be produced by the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`.

**Example:**

Define a UTC time:

```
time-test.core> (def t0 (date-time 2013 10 05 23 02 25 641))
#'time-test.core/t0
time-test.core> t0
#<DateTime 2013-10-05T23:02:25.641Z>
```

Convert it to a local time:

```
time-test.core> (def t1 (to-time-zone t0 (time-zone-for-offset -4)))
#'time-test.core/t1
time-test.core> t1
#<DateTime 2013-10-05T19:02:25.641-04:00>
```

Format the local time:

```
time-test.core> (unparse (formatter-local "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") t1)
"2013-10-05 19:02:25"
```